# Symfony Login with LDAP

Tags: php, symfony, ldap

I want to use LDAP in my Symfony (v3.0) Project to login my users.
But it seems to me, that a search_password can be either "hardcoded" in security.yml or null.

I have a simple login form with username and password. I want the password, that was entered here to be the search_password to search through the ldap.

Is this possible or do I break any conceptions here?

Thanks in advance
Max

Comment: search_password is linked to the LDAP account that will be used to check your users logins and password. It is not the same for all users.

Comment: So symfony ldap is designed to have a designated user, just for searching through the ldap?

Comment: No... It is to log users from your ldap. The 'search' user is responsible to find which users are allowed to login.

Comment: What do you mean with "log users"?

Comment: Authenticate a user with a login / password that's the goal of ldap.

Comment: This is my current setup

https://gist.github.com/chucky2305/cb00a1882e8fe7ad5b0d0657deec530d

In FormAuthenticator->checkCredentials().... this is the place where the password tha was entered in the form will be matched with the password, that belongs to the ldap user, or am i wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142908/discussion-between-coil-and-max-schindler).

Answer (score 1):

I got it done with the following security.yml

```
providers:
    dashboard_users:
        ldap:
            service: myldapservice
            base_dn: OU=User,OU=Company,DC=domain,DC=local
            search_dn: mydesignatedsearchuser
            search_password: designatedsearchuserpassword
            default_roles: ROLE_USER

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login_ldap:
            login_path: myloginroute
            check_path: myloginroute
            service: myldapservice
            dn_string: 'OurCompaniesDomainPrefix\{username}'

        logout:
            path: mylogoutroute
            target: /
```

Not i can login with a `sAMAccountName` like john.wayne
Hope this helps others.

Comment: Thank you! I got my LDAP service working with this info.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony uses a map-and-bind approach for [LDAP authentication](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html).  Users are asked to provide the sAMAccountName (your choice) along with their password to login.  Active Directory doesn't allow anonymous search - and you don't want to change that.  So, you need a service account to retrieve the user's distinguished name that is needed for a subsequent bind operation which completes the authentication.